# чекбокс запускающий яваскрипт

Tags: php, javascript

есть вот такой вот код

```
<script>
function boxDisable(e, t) {

        if (t.is(':checked')) {
          $(e).find('input').attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
          $(e).find('input').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }
</script>
    <form name="myForm" action="submit.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
    Birthday:<input type="date" name="fday"><br>
    Refferal: <input type="text" name="frefferal">
    Country: <input type="text" name="fcountry">
    City: <input type="text" name="fcity">
    Email:<input type="email" name="femail">
    <input type="radio" name="fgender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
    <input type="radio" name="fgender" value="female"> Female<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="faccept" onclick="boxDisable(appTimes, $(this));" value="Bike" >Accept<br>
    <input type="submit" name = "submitbtn" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

но почему то при нажатии на чекбокс ничего не происходит.
Мне нужно чтоб при выключенном чекбоксе кнопка субмит неработала а при включеном чекбоксе работала

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать вот так:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).on('change', 'input[name="faccept"]', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
      $('[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myForm" action="submit.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
    Birthday:<input type="date" name="fday"><br>
    Refferal: <input type="text" name="frefferal">
    Country: <input type="text" name="fcountry">
    City: <input type="text" name="fcity">
    Email:<input type="email" name="femail">
    <input type="radio" name="fgender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
    <input type="radio" name="fgender" value="female"> Female<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="faccept" value="Bike" >Accept<br>
    <input type="submit" name = "submitbtn" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Или используя функцию:

```js
function boxDisable(t) {
  if (t.is(':checked')) {
    $(t).parents('form').find('[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $(t).parents('form').find('[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myForm" action="submit.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="fname"> Birthday:
  <input type="date" name="fday"><br> Refferal: <input type="text" name="frefferal"> Country: <input type="text" name="fcountry"> City: <input type="text" name="fcity"> Email:
  <input type="email" name="femail">
  <input type="radio" name="fgender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="fgender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="faccept" onchange="boxDisable($(this));" value="Bike">Accept<br>
  <input type="submit" name="submitbtn" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: onclick так и оставить? он не будет выдавать ошибку?

Comment: да, забыл убрать, отредактировал ответ.

Comment: нижний код работает отлично только еще один вопрос как сделать чтоб при запуске сайта сначала кнопка была выключенной так как чекбокс выключен

Comment: можно сразу прописать для кнопки этот атрибут, без js, вручную в самом html.